# I have a 3 class classification problem. Detection of one of classes is very important. How to design the problem? one class classification or ...?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning

I have a 3 class classification problem. Correct detection of one of the classes is very important. How to design the problem:

1. one class classification?
2. a normal 3 class classification?
3. two distinct 2 class classification?(I mean, for example I have 3 lables A,B,C , and detection of class B is very important. Design a binary classification A,B and another binary classification B,C ?
4. or ....?
   Please recommend me!

Comment: What have you found and tried so far? Share with us that info. Also, what do you mean by "design a problem"? Maybe you mean "design an algorithm or model to solve this problem" or "describe the problem mathematically".

Answer (score 1):

When one class is more important than the others, you can simply use a higher sample weight for those and use normal three-class predictor.

Alternatively you can bias the network to a desired direction. Let's say the detection of class B is more important, and the model predicts class probabilities of 50%, 40% and 20% for classes A, B and C. You could "override" the prediction to B when ever its probability is above a certain threshold, for example 35%. Naturally this will increase the odds for false positives.

Maybe this threshold tuning is easier if you use "B vs. the rest" classifier first, you'll get clear false-positive vs. false-negative plots for given thresholds. The secondary classifier would be trained for an "A vs C" problem.

Comment: May be worth linking some examples of sample weight in use. In some libraries it may be called class weight (it can be viewed as "weighting a sample due to its class" or "weighting all samples of given class") so the name varies

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know which library the OP is using. I expect it is trivial to set the weights, and if not he may ask an other question.